# How to edit photo to be pleasing as a desktop wallpaper?

Tags: lightroom, photo-editing

I am using Adobe Lightroom to edit all my photos that I take with my Canon 70D. I shoot in RAW to preserve the detail of an image and have lately been wanting to "optimize" a lot of my photos for desktop wallpaper use.

Of course I can outright just set the photo as my wallpaper and it'll look *fine*. But there is something different about default wallpapers, for example, specifically the default wallpapers on Mac computers that gives it a much more pleasing look.

I'm really unsure if there is specific terminology for this, and I have tried to do as much research as possible on this topic, but I couldn't find much on the optimization of images for desktop wallpapers past cropping practices.

The best way I can describe it is that you can tell if a desktop wallpaper on somebody's computer is just a photo they took (even if it is a great photo overall) vs. one that someone may have downloaded from the internet, specifically posted as a wallpaper.

My question is, what are the general practices/ideologies in mind when optimizing your photo for desktop wallpaper use? What settings are primarily being changed and as a result producing that differentiating effect?

Thank you in advance for any ideas/help that can be given on this.

Comment: For best appearance, resize the image to the screen resolution before setting it as wallpaper. Experiment with file types to find what looks best to *you*: JPG, BMP etc.

Comment: An example of your photos would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great difference here is the vibrance, lighting and composition of the photo.
In a desktop background you don't want a specific focus but the whole photo has to shine and that has to do with the photo themselves.

I'm not sure if this apply but HDR looks better in a lot of cases.